# How to package a Maven project in zip file with jar files inside

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

**Small introduction**

I'm pretty new in maven and I face with the problem.
The structure of my project looks like this:

`|--root
   |--bin
      |-- some bash scripts
   |--config
      |-- some .properties files
   |--j2ee-apps
      |-- some web related files
   |--META-INF
      |-- MANIFEST.MF
   |--src
      |-- main
         |-- java
      |-- test
         |-- java`

**Goal**

After executing `mvn package` I have to get the .zip file with following structure:

`|--zip
   |--bin
      |-- some bash scripts
   |--config
      |-- config.jar   <-- jar with all .properties files inside
   |--j2ee-apps
      |-- some web related files
   |--META-INF
      |-- MANIFEST.MF
   |--lib
      |-- classes.jar  <-- jar with all .class files inside (from src folder)`

I've tried to use maven-assembly-plugin, but I didn't find examples that suit me.

Comment: You have explicit defined MANIFEST.MF so you are creating a OSGi bundle? Or what is the purpose of having defined a MANIFEST.MF of your own ?

Comment: I need an explicit defined MANIFEST.MF for ATG application. Because I'm working with atg platform.

Comment: Than default location for MANIFEST.MF file is `src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`..furthermore the properties into `src/main/resources` ...bash scripts into `src/main/scripts`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assembly.xml should looks like

```
<assembly>
     <id>zip</id>
     <formats>
       <format>zip</format>
     </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
     <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
     </dependencySet>
   </dependencySets>
   <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
     <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
     <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
     <includes>
       <include>*.jar</include>
     </includes>
    </fileSet> 
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/bin</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
      <filtered>true</filtered>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <!-- add fileSet entries for other folders under root -->
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I'm not sure if there any way to put META-INF just under zip not inside your project's jar file.

To change name of you jar you need maven-jar-plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>new_jar_name</finalName>                   
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I've packaged my project with assembly.xml provided by you. 
Looking into a final .zip file I found that lib/groupId-version.jar. I want to name this jar file exactly as classes.jar. Do you know how doing this?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Inner jar file didn't change name after adding maven-jar-plugin.

Comment: Updated assembly.xml in answer